# import pyPDF2 error on mac

Tags: python, macos

Installed pyPDF2 package through terminal
pip install pyPDF2
--No error

```
import pyPDF2
import docx
import string

pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("Accmanager.pdf", "rb"))
# Iterate pages
for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    # Extract text from page and add to content
content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
# Collapse whitespace
content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
```

Comment: No error? So what's wrong?

Comment: No error was shown during installation..But while running the code it's showing ImportError: No module named pyPDF2

Answer (score 1):

A minor correction in the spelling first letter 'p' should be capital, try this:

```
import PyPDF2
```

Comment: Same result-ImportError: No module named PyPDF2

Comment: Whats the output for: $ python -m pip list            #this should show PyPDF if installed.